# MIT app list from arduino error list empty

Tags: arduino

I need some guidance. I'm learning to send data from an arduino to MIT app inventor. I can send a serial data string and display it on the app. But I would like to split the string into variables. The program below I have running works but keeps giving an error that the list is empty. How can I only split the list when the list has contents.

Here is the arduino code

```html
void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
 
 int temp = 22;
 int var1 = 19;
 int Htemp = 85;
 Serial.print (temp);
 Serial.print ("?");
 Serial.print (var1);
 Serial.print ("?");
 Serial.print (Htemp);
 delay (2000);
}
```

[image: This is screen shot of MIT app]

Hope someone can help or point me in the right direction

Answer (score 0):

Worked out a way to get this to work, I added an if statement to check the list is full.

[image]